# Is GAE's method of serving django static files efficient?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-staticfiles

In the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) it mentions that in production using the built in server to serve static files is "grossly inefficient". However according to [Google App Engine's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) they do not recommend anything special to serve static files.

Does GAE do something on the backend to serve static files 'more efficiently'? Is the current implementation less than optimal? Is there a better way to serve static files?

I previously published on Heroku where it was best to use Amazon S3 to serve static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google docs aren't saying that Django should serve the static files, it's just saying that you should make use of the `staticfiles` app to collect your static files in a directory that will eventually be served by GAE.

You can read the documentation on actually [serving static files via GAE with python here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles)

> ... there are many cases where you want to serve static files directly to the web browser. Images, CSS stylesheets, JavaScript code, movies and Flash animations are all typically stored with a web application and served directly to the browser. App Engine can serve specific files directly without you having to code your own handler.